# How to insert greek letters in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

In IPython shell or Jupyter notebooks, we can use greek letters as variable names. For example to write σ, we type `\sigma` then we press `TAB` key to get σ.

I tried that in Pycharm, but it seems that doesn't work.
Is it possible to insert greek letters in pycharm in the same way as the example above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, PyCharm's Console doesn't support this. I created a feature request in the bug tracker to cover that https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-33730

**Update:** actually I forgot Live Templates, you can add one in **Settings | Editor | Live Templates**

[image]

and use `Cmd+J` to insert it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Please note that in my question I am looking for the feature in the editor itself not Pycharm console. Thank you

Comment: Oh, I see, there's no such feature too. Which OS do you use? I believe there should be some built-in ways to type greek letters.

Comment: In Windows just add the Greek keyboard layout in the computer settings and than switch layout (⊞ Win + Space) whenever you need Greek.

Answer (score 1):

[IntelliJ Plugin "Latex Symbol"](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18580-latex-symbol) has ~2,470 of such 'live templates' shown in accepted answer already defined for you ([source](https://github.com/tgeng/LatexSymbol/blob/main/src/main/resources/templates.xml)).
\delta -> δ
\Delta -> Δ
Better than [Another smaller plugin: "Greek Symbols"](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12793-greek-symbols)